# Google Streaming Speech Recognition on an Audio Stream Python

Tags: python, django, audio, google-speech-api

I have searched through all the available docs of Google but I could not find an example of streaming speech recognition on an audio stream in Python.

Currently, I am using Speech Recognition for Python in Django to get the audio from the user and then listen to the audio. I can then save the file and run the google speech recognition or directly from the instance of the audio created.

Can somebody guide me how to perform streaming speech recognition on an audio stream ?

Answer (score 5):

Google provides an example of the streaming Python API [here](https://github.com/googleapis/python-speech/blob/master/samples/snippets/transcribe_streaming.py).

Rather than opening an audio file to create the stream (as on line 34 of that example), pass the stream directly to the audio sample object (as on line 36).

Comment: @blambert it would be helpful if you could illustrate it with some code.

Comment: @indexOutOfBounds were you able to try it?

Answer (score 4):

This is a working [code](https://github.com/dawntcherian/Google-speech-to-text-python-websocket-server-using-microphone-stream) for the above requirement.

Code:

```
import asyncio
import websockets
import json
import threading
from six.moves import queue
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import types


IP = '0.0.0.0'
PORT = 8000

class Transcoder(object):
    """
    Converts audio chunks to text
    """
    def __init__(self, encoding, rate, language):
        self.buff = queue.Queue()
        self.encoding = encoding
        self.language = language
        self.rate = rate
        self.closed = True
        self.transcript = None

    def start(self):
        """Start up streaming speech call"""
        threading.Thread(target=self.process).start()

    def response_loop(self, responses):
        """
        Pick up the final result of Speech to text conversion
        """
        for response in responses:
            if not response.results:
                continue
            result = response.results[0]
            if not result.alternatives:
                continue
            transcript = result.alternatives[0].transcript
            if result.is_final:
                self.transcript = transcript

    def process(self):
        """
        Audio stream recognition and result parsing
        """
        #You can add speech contexts for better recognition
        cap_speech_context = types.SpeechContext(phrases=["Add your phrases here"])
        client = speech.SpeechClient()
        config = types.RecognitionConfig(
            encoding=self.encoding,
            sample_rate_hertz=self.rate,
            language_code=self.language,
            speech_contexts=[cap_speech_context,],
            model='command_and_search'
        )
        streaming_config = types.StreamingRecognitionConfig(
            config=config,
            interim_results=False,
            single_utterance=False)
        audio_generator = self.stream_generator()
        requests = (types.StreamingRecognizeRequest(audio_content=content)
                    for content in audio_generator)

        responses = client.streaming_recognize(streaming_config, requests)
        try:
            self.response_loop(responses)
        except:
            self.start()

    def stream_generator(self):
        while not self.closed:
            chunk = self.buff.get()
            if chunk is None:
                return
            data = [chunk]
            while True:
                try:
                    chunk = self.buff.get(block=False)
                    if chunk is None:
                        return
                    data.append(chunk)
                except queue.Empty:
                    break
            yield b''.join(data)

    def write(self, data):
        """
        Writes data to the buffer
        """
        self.buff.put(data)


async def audio_processor(websocket, path):
    """
    Collects audio from the stream, writes it to buffer and return the output of Google speech to text
    """
    config = await websocket.recv()
    if not isinstance(config, str):
        print("ERROR, no config")
        return
    config = json.loads(config)
    transcoder = Transcoder(
        encoding=config["format"],
        rate=config["rate"],
        language=config["language"]
    )
    transcoder.start()
    while True:
        try:
            data = await websocket.recv()
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            print("Connection closed")
            break
        transcoder.write(data)
        transcoder.closed = False
        if transcoder.transcript:
            print(transcoder.transcript)
            await websocket.send(transcoder.transcript)
            transcoder.transcript = None

start_server = websockets.serve(audio_processor, IP, PORT)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(start_server)
asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Comment: Is there a way to read this audio stream from a Google Cloud Storage bucket for example?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a React web app to stream client's audio, then you can refer to this repository for code samples (or you could just clone it and add your proprietary code) https://github.com/saharmor/realtime-transcription-playground