# How to use google speech recognition on audio streaming from a url (Python)?

Tags: python, speech-recognition, google-speech-api

Currently trying to figure out how to use Google's speech recognition on audio streaming from a URL.

So far I've got the URL to play audio through Python with VLC, to test that I could actually stream that audio at all, but now I'm not quite sure what to do.

The closest example I've found was Google's example code on using their speech recognition on audio streaming from a microphone, but I'm not sure how to transfer that over to audio from a URL.

Any tips? Thanks!

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44088246/google-streaming-speech-recognition-on-an-audio-stream-python

Comment: Did you get any solution?